# Demystifying and understanding shortcode nomenclature

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

A code snippet from the Tuts Plus →

```
function link($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "to" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com'
    ), $atts));
    return '<a href="'.$to.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}
```

[Source Link →](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way--wp-17165)

## Question →

How to reproduce `"$to"` in the shortcode?

I tried this →

`[link $to= "https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/"]` But this didnt worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `[link to= "https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/"]`.

This is a textbook example of why `extract()` is bad. You can't easily tell where variables are coming from. `extract()` creates variables out of an array with the keys becoming the variable name. So this part:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "to" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com'
), $atts));
```

Is creating an array with a `to` key, set to `http://net.tutsplus.com` if it's not defined in `$atts`. Then it's `extract()`ed so that the `to` key becomes `$to`.

You should avoid using `extract()` and just use the `$atts` variable:

```
function link($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        "to" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com'
    ), $atts);
    return '<a href="'.$atts['to'].'">'.$content.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: `You should avoid using extract() and just use the $atts variable:` → this is a Million dollar advise. thank you so much, sir.